# Adjusting simultaneously for multiple confounders

Tags: generalized-linear-model, confounding, adjustment

I am having trouble understanding how to adjust for confounders in a basic statistical analysis. As a simple example, assume I want to know whether the weight of group of sick subjects and a group of healthy subjects is significantly different. Since the weight of a person also depends on gender and age, I want to adjust for these confounders.

1) The most common way I found to do it is to use generalized-linear-model (GLM), and to write $Y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \cdot AGE +\alpha_2 \cdot GENDER$, where $Y$ is the weight. After I find the coefficients $\alpha_i$, based on fitting to all the subjects (in both groups), I should then change all the weights (both in the sick people group and in the healthy people group) to $Y^* -Y$, where $Y^*$ is the measured weight and $Y$ is the weight predicted by the GLM, and only then perform a z-test or a t-test. Am I right? Is it more reasonable to find the coefficients based only on the healthy subjects and then adjust only for the sick?

2) Are there any alternative methods to adjust for two confounders? I know I can theoretically take the dependence to be exponential, or quadratic, etc... But is there any way (except for simple plotting) by which I would know what is the correct way of adjusting? Any systematic way of doing the adjustment? Any alternatives to GLM?